# Python selenium browser not finding img tags when they are not on the page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

def get_image_links(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Tut10\Desktop\PSTool-Python\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(url)

    images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
    image_list = []
    new_list = []

    mpn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="productinfo_ctn"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h2[1]')[0].text
    mpn = mpn.split(' ')[2]

    for image in images:
        if mpn in image.get_attribute('src'):
            correct_model_image = image.get_attribute('src')
            if "145.jpg" in correct_model_image:
                #print(correct_model_image)
                image_list.append(correct_model_image)

    print('--------------')
    for x in range(int(len(image_list) / 2)):
        new_list.append((image_list[x]))

    return new_list

get_image_links('https://www.homedepot.com/p/Avanti-Pro-12-in-x-80-Tooth-Fine-Finish-Saw-Blade-2-Pack-P128080PP/202519463')
```

I am trying to get all the images on this link but it's not coming up with any even though they are obviously on the page and when I checked the source code of the page they appeared. Why is selenium not grabbing any info in the images declaration? Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are pulling the model number from the page and it looks like "P128080PP" but in the image `src` the P's are lowercase (-p128080pp-) so it's not matching in the line below

```
if mpn in image.get_attribute('src'):
```

There's a much easier way to do this.

You are pulling all `IMG` tags, then matching on the model number, then matching on `145.jpg`. You can do all of this in a single locator to avoid scraping the page multiple times and looping. You are also cutting your list in half at the end. I'm assuming this is because you are finding all the images on the page which includes things like Frequently Bought Together, More In This Collection, etc. I'm assuming you really only want the images from the product area. These are all in the `<div id="thumbnails" ...>` container. You can also add this to the locator so that you only get the images you want in one locator.

```
def get_image_links(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Tut10\Desktop\PSTool-Python\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(url)

    model_no = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h2.modelNo").text.split(' ')[2].lower()
    image_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#thumbnails img[src$='145.jpg'][src*='" + model_no + "']")

    return image_list
```

The first line gets the model number. I changed the locator to be shorter and less fragile. I did the same `split()` but changed it to lowercase so that it will match with the `src` in the images.

The next line grabs all the images under the `<div id="thumbnails" ...>` where the `src` ends with `145.jpg` and contains the model number.